# How to aggregate details in Pentaho Report Designer (PRD) 3.9?

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-report-designer

Very new to Pentaho Reporting,

I have a query grabbing columns `categories`, `quantity`, and `gross`.  It returns about 200 rows.

Without changing the query, is there a way for the report to display the aggregates for each category (I have category as a group)? For example, `All you can eat` should only display a sum of the `Amount` and `GrossValue` columns.

### Same for `dessert` (notice there are two group headers - why?)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You just need to get used to with pentaho report designer.
Refer information given at the end of this page [simple report](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/Reporting/01.+Creating+Your+First+Report).

You can add one parameter in group footer and set its properties.
They provides properties like aggregation-type, which can be set as Sum or count and then it will show at the end of each group with sum or count of the rows as per the type you specified.

Comment: How do you hide or not show the details?  Under group footer, I am able to see the sums but even if I remove the fields from details, it shows empty rows representing as-if there were fields there.

Comment: Ok figured that out by using the structure tab.  Right now the desserts still show multiple times.  How can I aggregate such that desserts only shows once?

Comment: You need to be sure the query is sorted by desserts. When grouping your sort order must match the group(s)